# Partition won't come up in hdd

Tags: windows-10, ssd, permissions

I've upgraded the hard drive on my laptop. I used a program to copy partition C to SSD, and now I'm writing from laptop working on SSD. So perfect. BUT...

I plugged old HDD in my **second** laptop, and I was trying to access some folders and Windows give me "You do not have permission to this folder". I clicked Continue, then in the middle of the process, I think "giving me permissions" I canceled it.

The result on the laptop, which HDD came from, I can not see this partition, and I can only see it in my **second** laptop.

Is there any way to fix it?

Ps no, it is not someone's disk and I'm not trying to access inappropriate/private data. I just want to have a backup, and it's not giving me rest.

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved.
In diskmgmt.msc, there is an option "Add drive letter or path."

I selected the drive letter (here: G:) and partition appeared in now-external HDD!
FYI